# spell checker js url post request not working

Tags: spell-checking

I have installed spell checker plugin and it is working in the example given in the folder, but when I call using a URL it is not giving any result. This is the URL
    http://localhost/spellcheck/src/webservices/php/SpellChecker.php?lang=en&driver=pspell&action=get_incorrect_words&text[]=whta

Comment: we can't see what is on your localhost...... you would need to post it (or your computer) on the web for us to see it

Comment: Post the code that isn't working and examples of it not working: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the spelling in the URL you can create a PHP script to manually check and correct the spelling.

here is an example

our url is `127.0.0.1/the-wolrd-needs-you` as you can see there is a spelling error and we want to correct it. We'll create a PHP Script.

```
$correct_url = 127.0.0.1/the-world-needs-you //correct url
$url = 127.0.0.1/the-wolrd-needs-you

//To detect if there is a spelling error
if($url==$correct_url) {
   //Do Nothing
} else {
   header("Location: 127.0.0.1/the-world-needs-you")
}
```

Hope that will help you :) I'm sorry if didn't or it's kinda off topic XD